# Connection String in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, web-services, connection-string

How i can use ODP tool for oracle connection while working with VB.NET web service in the following web service in order to retrieve data from an oracle? The query that I would like to use is

SELECT ALIQUOT_ID FROM ALIQUOT

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" Codebehind="Aliquot.asmx.vb" Class="Aliquot" %>

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports System.Type
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

<WebService([Namespace]:="http://myservices.com/webservices/")> _
Public Class Aliquot
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod(Description:="Get Aliquot_IDs from Aliquot table")> _
Public Function GetAliquot_ID(ByVal aliquot_id As Integer) As Integer     
    Return (aliquot_id)
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is **not** deprecated by Oracle. There is no reason not to use it. However, `System.Data.OracleClient` provided by Microsfoft is deprecated and should not be used in new projects. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` is quite new and seems to have still a couple of bugs.

Comment: @Loic, I have not worked with viewing data in XML format before. You might want to change your question title/tag to reflect what you are actually looking for. And Wernfried is correct. Sorry if I caused confusion.